# VBA case insensitive sorting within listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below which is used to remove duplicates and sort the values alphabetically into a listbox within a userform but it is prioritizing uppercase over alphabetical and I would like it to ignore the case of the text

```
    Dim Coll As Collection, cell As Range, LastRow As Long
    Dim blnUnsorted As Boolean, i As Integer, temp As Variant
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set SourceSheet = Worksheets("Groups")
    
    '///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    'Populate the ListBox with unique Make items from column A.
    LastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Coll = New Collection
    'Open a With structure for the ListBox control.
    With ClientInput
        .Clear
        For Each cell In SourceSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
            'Only attempt to populate cells containing a text or value.
            If Len(cell.Value) <> 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Coll.Add cell.Text, cell.Text
                If Err.Number = 0 Then .AddItem cell.Text
                End If
        Next cell
            blnUnsorted = True
            Do
            blnUnsorted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(.List) - 1
                If .List(i) > .List(i + 1) Then
                    temp = .List(i)
                    .List(i) = .List(i + 1)
                    .List(i + 1) = temp
                    blnUnsorted = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        Loop While blnUnsorted = True
    'Close the With structure for the ListBox control.
    End With
```

Current

AC

AZ

ab

Desired

ab

AC

AZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 If .List(i) > .List(i + 1) Then
```

use

```
 If LCase(.List(i)) > LCase(.List(i + 1)) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the worksheetfunction `sort`

This is a sample code of how to use it

```
Sub sortRange()
Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Selection

Dim arrValues As Variant
arrValues = WorksheetFunction.Sort(rg)

rg.Offset(, 2).Resize(3).Value = arrValues

End Sub
```

If A1:A3 are selected the above code will write the sorted values to C1:C3

[image]

You can iterate over the array to add the items to the list

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It firstly places the existing range (from A:A) in an array, sorts the range in place, places the sorted range in another array, extract unique strings (case sensitive) using a `Dictionary` and load the list box directly from the array using its `List` property. Then, places back the initial extracted array before sorting:

```
Sub UniqueSortLoadListBox()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSort, i As Long, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = Worksheets("Groups")
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value
   
    With sh.Sort 'the fastest sorting way
       .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR), _
                 SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = True
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row ' recalculate to eliminate the empty cells
    arrSort = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value                       'place the sorted range in an array, for faster iteration/processing
    
    'extract unique strings (case sensitive)
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = BinaryCompare 'case sensitive for keys creation
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSort)
        dict(arrSort(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i
    
    'load the listbox directly from an array (dictionary keys array)
    With clientInput
        .Clear
        .List = dict.Keys
    End With
   
   'place back the array as it was before sorting and unique extracting:
   sh.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr  
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

### Sorted Column Values to a List Box

**If You Don't Have 365**

- In a nutshell, the code will write the values from the criteria column to a helper column, the column adjacent to the right of the used range, sort it, retrieve its values, clear its contents, and populate a list box with the retrieved unique (sorted) values.

```vb
Sub PopulateClientInput()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Populate Client Input"

    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "Groups"
    Const cCol As Long = 1
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' It is assumed that the worksheet's used range consists of a valid table
    ' (not an Excel table) i.e. one row of headers and contiguous data below.
    
    ' Reference the expanded data range ('rg') i.e. the data range (no headers)
    ' and an extra helper column to the right. Retrieve the range's
    ' number of rows ('rCount') and columns ('cCount').
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' shrink
        If rCount = 0 Then ' only headers or empty worksheet
            MsgBox "Not enough rows.", vbExclamation, ProcTitle
            Exit Sub
        End If
        cCount = .Columns.Count + 1 ' expand
        ' Note that the following cannot happen if 'cCol = 1'.
        If cCount < cCol + 1 Then ' criteria column not in used range
            MsgBox "Not enough columns.", vbExclamation, ProcTitle
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Reference the range.
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount, cCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the criteria column range ('crg').
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(cCol)
    
    ' Store the sorted values from the criteria column range
    ' in a 2D one-based (one-column) array, the criteria array ('cData').
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim cData() As Variant
    
    If rCount > 1 Then  ' multiple cells
        ' Reference the helper column range ('hrg').
        Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Columns(cCount)
        ' Write the values from the criteria column range
        ' to the helper column range.
        hrg.Value = crg.Value
        ' Sort the helper column range.
        hrg.Sort hrg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
        ' Store the sorted values from the sorted helper column range
        ' in the criteria array.
        cData = hrg.Value
        ' Clear the contents of the helper column range.
        hrg.ClearContents
    Else ' one cell
        ' Store the single value in the single element of the criteria array.
        ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = crg.Value
    End If
        
    ' Store the unique values from the criteria array in the 'keys'
    ' of a dictionary ('dict').
    ' The 'items' are irrelevant but will hold 'Empty'.
    ' Error values and blanks are excluded.
        
    ' Define the dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive i.e. 'A = a'
    
    Dim cKey As Variant ' Current Value in the Criteria Array
    Dim r As Long ' Current Row in the Criteria Array
    
    ' Store the unique valus in the dictionary.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        cKey = cData(r, 1) ' retrieve the current value
        If Not IsError(cKey) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(CStr(cKey)) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                ' Check if the current value exists in the dictionary.
                ' This is not necessary but will ensure that the first occuring
                ' string's case is used. Otherwise, the last would be used.
                If Not dict.Exists(cKey) Then
                    dict(cKey) = Empty ' store the unique value in a 'key'
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Populate the list box with the sorted unique values
    ' from the dictionary and inform.
    
    With ClientInput
        
        ' Validate the dictionary.
        If dict.Count = 0 Then
            .Clear ' or not?
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "No valid data.", vbExclamation, ProcTitle
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        .List = dict.Keys ' 'dict.Keys' is a zero-based (1D) array
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Client input populated.", vbInformation, ProcTitle
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```